# Account Manager + Cookie Based Authentication

Tags: android, flask, accountmanager, android-authenticator

Is it possible to use Android Account Manager using Cookie-based authentication? How (a code with a explanation would be much appreciated)?

I have seen many examples regarding authentication token, but that is not the case. I have just implemented cookie-based authentication on Python FLASK.

OBS.: I'm using Android Volley for the requests of the application.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is to add this line in `onCreate` in your `Application` class:

```
CookieHandler.setDefault(new CookieManager());
```

this line will make your `HttpUrlConnection` hold cookies like browser, and since most of the http agents like `Volley` or `okHttp` are based on `HttpUrlConnection` they also will hold your cookies )

Comment: Have you got some explanation about how to implement "AbstractAccountAuthenticator", considering this code? Some explanation would be much appreciated :).

Comment: From what I understand `HttpUrlConnection` is [based on OkHttp](https://twitter.com/JakeWharton/status/482563299511250944), not the other way around. So this wouldn't work with OkHttp; you would need to extend the [`CookieJar`](https://twitter.com/JakeWharton/status/482563299511250944) class to sync the cookies with the `CookieManager`. I'm not sure about Volley, but I wouldn't jump to any conclusions.